# To check the date of creation of a role in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I create many roles in SSRS and I want to delete the oldest one .So I want to view the date of creation of
roles in ssrs.

Comment: The `dbo.PolicyUserRole` table in the `ReportServer` should have the details you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

**To delete or modify a role definition**

1. In Object Explorer, expand a report server node.
2. Expand the Security folder.
3. To delete or modify an item-level role definition, expand the Roles folder. Perform one of the following:
4. To delete a role definition, right-click the item and click Delete. The Delete Object dialog box is displayed. Click OK.

I hope this will help you

Thanks
Venky